# Simple jQuery GET request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I just can't figure out why my script isn't working. I tried several solutions I found here, also tried using `.ajax()`, but no results.

I must've missed something because it's not the first time I'm using .get or making something similar.

```
<div class="test"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var btc = getBTC(10);

        $('.test').html(btc);
    });

    function getBTC(val) {
        $.get("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=EUR&value=" + val, function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
</script>
```

If I change `return data;` to `console.log(data);` then execute `getBTC(10);` in the console it works fine. I'm a little bit confused here.

Comment: `$.get` is async.

Comment: Replace `return data` with `$('.test').html(data);` or look for other solutions as mentioned in the marked question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $.get("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=EUR&value=" + val, function(data) {
     $('.test').html(data);
   });
</script>
```

Your code is asynchronous. This means that the response is not ready yet. You have to wait for it. Only then you can use `data` as a value.